# CodeIgniter - Update Database Record

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

I've done the coding of Update Database record in Codeigniter. Everything works fine but When I click the Save button database records won't update. Each time it's showing the old database records. I want to update the database records but what's wrong with this. I don't understand the missing thing. Help Needed.

My Controller:

```
    <?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Employee extends CI_Controller {


    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();              
        if($this->session->email == "")
        {
            redirect('login');
        }
        $this->load->model('EmployeeModel','EmployeeModel');
    }   

    public function ViewEmployee()
    {
        $data['getEmployee'] = $this->EmployeeModel->getEmployee(); 

        $this->load->view('view_employee',$data);
    }


        public function update($empID) {

            $data['user'] = $this->EmployeeModel->get_by($empID);
            $data['subview'] = 'Employee/edit_employee';
            $this->load->view('edit_employee', $data);
        }
        public function edit() {

            $empID = $this->input->post('empID');


                                    //Check whether user upload picture
            if(!empty($_FILES['picture']['name'])){
                $config['upload_path'] = 'uploads/';
                $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|png|gif';
                $config['file_name'] = $_FILES['picture']['name'];

                //Load upload library and initialize configuration
                $this->load->library('upload',$config);
                $this->upload->initialize($config);

                if($this->upload->do_upload('picture')){
                    $uploadData = $this->upload->data();
                    $picture = $uploadData['file_name'];
                }else{
                    $picture = '';
                }
            }else{
                $picture = '';
            }

            $data =  array(
                    'empFirstName' => $this->input->post('firstname'),
                    'empLastName' => $this->input->post('lastname'),
                    'empNO' => $this->input->post('employee_id'),
                    'designation' => $this->input->post('designation'),
                    );

            $this->db->where('empID', $empID);
            $this->db->update('tbl_employee', $data);

            redirect('view_employee');

        $this->update($empID);

    }
}
```

My Model:

```
<?php
class EmployeeModel extends CI_Model
{
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function EmployeeRegister($data)
    {
        $this->db->insert('tbl_employee',$data);
        return true;
    }

    public function getEmployee()
    {
        $this->db->where('status',0);
        $query = $this->db->get('tbl_employee');
        return $query->result();
    }

    public function get_by($empID) {
        $this->db->where('empID', $empID);
        $user = $this->db->get('tbl_employee')->row();
        return $user;
    }   
}
```

View:

```
<?php 
print_r($user)
?>
                                <?php echo form_open('Employee/edit'); ?>
                                    <div class="row">

                                        <div class="form-titles"> Personal Information</div>
                                        <div class="col-lg-4 input_field_sections">
                                            <h5>Employee Name <span style="color: #cc0000">*</span></h5>
                                            <input required type="text" class="form-control" name="firstname" value="<?=$user->empFirstName?>"/>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="col-lg-4 input_field_sections">
                                            <h5>Father's Name <span style="color: #cc0000">*</span></h5>
                                            <input required type="text" class="form-control" name="lastname" value="<?=$user->empLastName?>"/>
                                        </div>
                                      </div>


                                    <div class="row">

                                        <div class="col-lg-4 input_field_sections">
                                            <h5>NIC <span style="color: #cc0000">*</span></h5>
                                            <input required type="text" class="form-control" name="cnic" value="<?=$user->cnic?>"/>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="col-lg-4 input_field_sections">
                                            <h5>Date of Birth <span style="color: #cc0000">*</span></h5>
                                            <input required="" type="text" class="form-control datepicker" name="birth_date" value="<?=$user->birth_date?>"/>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>


                                    <div class="row">

                                          <div class="col-lg-4 input_field_sections">
                                            <h5>Mobile #<span style="color: #cc0000">*</span></h5>
                                            <input required="" type="text" class="form-control" name="mobile" value="<?=$user->empMobile?>"/>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="col-lg-4 input_field_sections">
                                            <h5>Phone #</h5>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="phone" value="<?=$user->phone?>"/>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>

                                    <div class="row">

                                         <div class="col-lg-4 input_field_sections">
                                            <h5>Email ID</h5>
                                            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="<?=$user->empemail?>"/>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="col-lg-4 input_field_sections">
                                            <h5>Current Photo</h5>
                                            <input type="file" class="form-control" name="picture" value="<?=$user->picture?>"/>

                                                <img src="<?php echo base_url().'uploads/'.$user->picture?>" style="width: 150px;height: auto;" />

                                        </div>

                                    </div>

                                       <div class="row">

                                        <div class="col-lg-8 input_field_sections">
                                            <h5>Address / City <span style="color: #cc0000">*</span></h5>
                                            <textarea required="" name="address" class="addres form-control" /><?=$user->empaddress?></textarea>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>


                                     <div class="row">

                                        <div class="form-titles" style="margin-top:40px;"> Job Information</div>


                                        <div class="col-lg-4 input_field_sections">
                                            <h5>Work Location <span style="color: #cc0000">*</span></h5>
                                            <input required type="text" class="form-control" name="worklocation" value="<?=$user->worklocation?>"/>
                                        </div>

                                          <div class="col-lg-4 input_field_sections">
                                            <h5>Employee ID <span style="color: #cc0000">*</span></h5>
                                            <input required type="text" class="form-control" name="employee_id" value="<?=$user->empNO?>"/>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>


                                     <div class="row">

                                        <div class="col-lg-4 input_field_sections">
                                            <h5>Department <span style="color: #cc0000">*</span></h5>
                                            <input required="" type="text" class="form-control" name="department" value="<?=$user->department?>"/>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="col-lg-4 input_field_sections">
                                            <h5>Designation <span style="color: #cc0000">*</span></h5>
                                            <input required type="text" class="form-control" name="designation" value="<?=$user->designation?>"/>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>



                                        <div class="col-lg-8 input_field_sections">
                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
```

Comment: don't upload all code. precised the question

Comment: In `Model` `EmployeeRegister` function add these lines `print_r($data); exit;`

Comment: This piece of code makes no sense to me `redirect('user');$this->update($empID);`

Comment: @BilalAhmed Problem is with Update not with the Register function.

Comment: can you show the scheme of the database table you are using i assume it is 'tbl_employee'

Comment: since you try to access to `$empID = $this->input->post('empID');`
Where is your hidden field `empID`? I don't see it...

Comment: @samehanwar Yes, database table is tbl_employee.

Comment: @Mehreen yes , can you please show the table fields because i think your problem is mistake in one field

Comment: @sintakonte Great. I was missing the empID hidden value. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Use this one to debug your application.

echo $this->db->last_query();